# What is the fastest and most elegant way to change a matrix dimension?

Tags: matrices

I have been writing code for a paper and I'm reading an image in RGB space in OpenCV which means that its read as a 3D matrix (HEIGHT x WIDTH x 3 (RGB) ).

I'm reshaping the image into a 2D matrix ( NB_PIXELS x 3 (RGB) ) using this code :

```
image = image.reshape(len(image) * len(image[0]), len(image[0][0]))
```

This reshaping process is an important step in the method that I'm going over in the paper.

Since I can't have the paper depend on a library like NumPy I would like a more elegant way to explain the reshaping. Are there any papers that I can reference or any equations, methods ..etc that I can use as a replacement to the code that I shared ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I would consider a sentence such as this to be unambiguous:

> We flattened the $h \times w \times 3$ input data down to a two-dimensional $hw \times 3$ shape.

I don't believe a reference explaining this would be necessary.

Comment: You're right. But, the reshaping speed of the matrix is very important in the process. For example, Numpy reshapes very large matrices in 20~100 ms from my tests. Which is perfect. Now, I need to be able to explain a reshaping method that can be as fast without mentioning the numpy library. As the paper I'm writing is about creating a faster way to execute a certain algorithm that I'm working on, I have optimized the other steps of the process myself (my own algorithm) except for the reshaping of the matrix which I did using the reshape numpy method.

Comment: @HammiCloud Eh... you do realize that `numpy.reshape` doesn't actually change the data stored at all, right? 'Reshaping' is just re-interpreting the data that's already there. It's essentially a no-op.

Comment: Yes i do. I would like a way to explain that interpretation (the memory mapping) ..